# Creating anchor texts for SEO

Tags: php, seo

I have the below code. I want to create anchor texts for SEO.

```
echo"<td style='vertical-align:top;text-align:center;width:500px;'><br><b><a href='/Ad-item/".$row['MyAdsId']."/".$BusinessName1."/". $AdTitle."' style='color:black;'>".$row['AdTitle']."</b><br><br>".substr($desc, 0, 150)."... read more</a><br><br></td>";
```

substr($desc, 0, 150) is the variable that defines the anchor text. I want to ask whether such big variables are conducive to be used as anchor texts because i'm only getting less than ten clicks per day from google search. I have searched many blogs and i'm really confused on how to go about anchor texts.
Please i kindly request for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A large amount of text is perfectly valid for the <a> tag - W3's page about links in HTML5 is available [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html).

If your $desc variable contains any html tags, then it may not validate, however. (The strip_tags() function will help you out if that is the case.)

Ultimately, most SEO is based on external elements such as links to your site.  However, if you really want to optimise your links for on-site SEO, then you'd probably need to write them individually rather than relying on auto-generating them.

Comment: for example how about this text in this link http://www.deffsale.com/221/1/Favour-Amazing-Interior-Designs/

Comment: Your link text for each product is exactly the same.  If users cannot tell your pages apart from reading the text, then Google will not be able to (only Google know how Google actually work - which is why this site is not really for SEO questions).  Length shouldn't matter, but link text should describe what it is actually linking to for usability as much as SEO.